# tabu and space between columns

Tags: spacing, columns, tabu

I have aproblem with column widths in tabu environment. I set dimensions of tables and columns. First columns should have the same width = 5cm, First and second table should have the same width = 19cm. But there is a significant shift = purple rectangle on an image. How can I fix it? I need to define total width of table and widths of columns. But i have no idea how:) So please help me

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\settrims{0mm}{0mm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{10mm}{*}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabu} to 19cm {|X[5cm,p,l]|X[11cm,p,l]X[3cm,p,r]|}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{ \textit{ \textls[100]{bla bla} } } \\
        \toprule
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\

    \end{tabu}
    \begin{tabu} to 19cm {|X[5cm,p,l]|X[14cm,p,l]|}
        \addlinespace[1cm]
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{ \textit{ \textls[100]{bla bla} } } \\
        \toprule
        bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
        bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
        bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
    \end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, I've adjusted your code not to have bad boxes. If you omit the `tabu` length then it uses `\linewidth`.

If you use all columns of type `X` then the space is divided into the columns depending on the first parameter you give to the column.

So, specifying `X[5]` is not the same as specifying `p{5cm}`.

Moreover, the right way to specify an `X` column is (commas can be omitted):

```
X[<coef>,<align>,<type>]
```

where `<coef>` scales the widths of the `X` columns, if there are more than one `X` column and takes into consideration the length `\tabcolsep`, `<align>` is the horizontal alignment (either `r`, `c`, `l` or `j` (default)) and `<type>` is the vertical alignment (either `p` (default), `m` or `b`).

Specifying

```
X[5cm,p,l]
```

is wrong for a few reasons: you are specifying a width coefficient of 5 (`5`), a centered column (`c`) and a column type `m`. Then you are redefining things adding `p` which overwrites `m` and `r` which overwrites `c`. The right definition in this case would have been:

```
X[5,l,p]
```

where `p` can be omitted since it's the default.

If you want the result you're expecting, it is better to use fixed width columns and *only* the last one calculated (`X`).

This means that this is the right code to use:

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\settrims{0mm}{0mm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{10mm}{*}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabu} {|p{5cm}|p{11cm}X[r]|}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{ \textit{ \textls[100]{bla bla} } } \\
        \toprule
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\
        bla bla                     & bla bla           & bla \\

    \end{tabu}
    \begin{tabu} {|p{5cm}|X[l]|}
        \addlinespace[1cm]
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{ \textit{ \textls[100]{bla bla} } } \\
        \toprule
        bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
        bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
        bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
    \end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When using `p{5cm}` I get warnings for `Underfull \hbox in paragraph` every time I leave an empty column. Is there anything I can do about it (while keeping fixed width column) ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga I'sorry, but I'm not able to reproduce your behavior with the settings in my answer.